# Security proof about RFC 6979

Tags: dsa, rfc6979

In [the paper: "The Random Oracle Model: a Twenty-Year
Retrospective"](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/140.pdf), section 7.3 by Koblitz & Menezes,the authors tried to prove the security of ECDSA+.

But after looking at the entire proof, I didn’t find that they considered the probability that both forgers would choose the same $M$ and $R'$ for the $j$-th time.

In my cognition, after considering the probability of simultaneously selecting $M$ and $R'$, the probability of an attacker successfully breaking the elliptic curve discrete logarithm problem may become negligible.

Does this proof need not consider the probability of $M$ and $R'$? Or am I misunderstanding the proof?